# Angularjs include an empty option in html select using ng-repeat - Umbraco back end with Angularjs 1.1.5

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, umbraco

As the title says I get an empty option in my HTML when I'm using `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options`. The reason I'm using ng-repeat instead of ng-options is to be able to set a class on every option depending on it's value. I tried using a directive with ng-options but I did not achieve desired result. The problem is not that the default selected value is not set as you can see from the generated HTML. I have a suspicion that the empty option comes from the select ng-model but I'm not sure.

My HTML looks like this:

```
        <select ng-model="selectedProduct.code" ng-init="selectFirstProduct()" ng-change="getArticle()" size="8">
            <option ng-selected="{{product.code == selectedProduct.code}}" ng-repeat="product in productsForPriceList" ng-class="getClassForProduct(product )" value="{{product.code}}">{{product.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

This results in HTML to look like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedProduct.code" ng-change="getArticle()" size="8" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<option value="? string:200230 ?"></option>
<!-- ngRepeat: product in productsForPriceList -->
<option ng-selected="true" ng-repeat="product in productsForPriceList" ng-class="getClassForProduct(product)" value="200230" class="ng-scope ng-binding" selected="selected">Product 1</option>
<option ng-selected="false" ng-repeat="product in productsForPriceList" ng-class="getClassForProduct(product)" value="300025" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Product 2</option>
<option ng-selected="false" ng-repeat="product in productsForPriceList" ng-class="getClassForProduct(product)" value="300206" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Product 3</option>
```

I'm using `ng-init="selectFirstProduct()"` to set `selectedProduct.code` to the first value in the list. However if I omit this code and set selectedProduct.code when I'm getting the list the result is still the same.

I'm using Umbraco version 7.3.5 back end with Angularjs version 1.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `selectedProduct.code` and it will eliminate the blank option from the list.

**Initialize the Object**

```
$scope.selectedProduct = {};
```

**Set A default to the List**

```
$scope.productsForPriceList.YourObjectKey.IsDefault = true;
```

**Add this line code to Controller to initialize your option**

```
$scope.selectedProduct.code = $filter('filter')($scope.productsForPriceList, {IsDefault: true})[0];
```

You need to add the dependency `$filter` to the controller

Comment: This solution did not work for me unfortunately. `$scope.productsForPriceList` is also dynamic so your code would be quite error prone even if it worked the first time I think.